# Using functions from a class that is created as a template in the host class

Tags: c++, function, class, templates

I have 3 classes. The first class (List) stores a linked list of the Node class, and each Node class has a pointer to the next Node and a T data variable to store the data in the third class, StudentData.

If from the List class, I needed to access functions of the StudentData class, I'd have to go through the Node class of course, but I'm not sure how to do that.

For instance if I have a function that writes the whole list to a file, accessing the elements as so

```
void storeList() {
//create fileObj
Node<T> * temp = pFront;

while (temp != nullptr) {
    fileObj << temp->getData(); //line 121
    temp = temp->getPNext();
}
```

How would I access the overloaded operator as defined in the StudentData class?

```
template <class T>
class List {
private:
    Node<T> * pFront;
public:
    void storeList();
    //getters and setters

template <class T>
class Node {
private:
    Node<T> * pNext;
    T data;
    //getters and setters

class StudentData {
private:
    int recNum;
    int idNum;
    string first, last;
    //ect
public:
    void exFuncion();
    fstream &operator<< (fstream &out, StudentData data);
```

One of my ideas was to make something like this

```
void storeList() {
//create fileObj
Node<T> * temp = pFront;

while (temp != nullptr) {
T tempData
tempData = temp->getData();
fileObj << tempData;
    temp = temp->getPNext();
}
```

but thats probably redundant.

If it helps, I get an error

> list.h(121): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right->hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

As its trying to convert a T to a StudentData, but that doesnt make much sense to me.

Comment: There is no operator `>>` in the code you present. What's on line `144` in `list.h`? Please add [mcve]

Comment: My bad, fixed. Its the same error ( I have several overloaded operators)